# speed of FFT Jtransformation vs MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab, fft

i have vector about {1850 000,1} elements in JTransfroms.. 
but log:

```
exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 1350 000
```

it works...but still it takes about 1 minute!! its too much for me..with threads..
in matlab it takes about 2 sec.  In official web of Jtrans.

> :limitations: 1D transforms for not power-of-two sizes are sequential
>   (when the mixed-radix is used).  1D transforms for power-of-two sizes
>   can use only 2 or 4 threads.
>
> The number of threads must be a power-of-two number.

Can someone explain what is this power-of-two sizes?

Answer (score 0):

power of two are the (with computers so present) numbers that have only the factor 2. Thats 2, 4, 8, 16, ..., 1024 2048 etc. So if you use as input a vector with exactly 1024 numbers, it should go faster.

I can't really tell what you mean by "about {1850 000,1} elements", though maybe your number is much higher? The library will not use more than 4 threads obviuosly (wouldn't do much on many systems anyway), so you should not get to much of a speed gain. Maybe there is another problem involved.

Comment: thanks ok j have this numbber 1843200 a its power of two :) its myabye problem when i calling method with same object

Comment: @LukasTheBoss: 1843200 is not a power of two (since you can divide it by 5 (last digit is a zero)). If you can, you should use the FFT (in any library) with a number of elements that is a pure power of two: it simplifies the calculations and hence speeds them up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post a little background of the FFT to explain the radix-2 limitation.

The first thing to note is that most FFT implementations use the [C-T FFT Algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm) This works by splitting an FFT into smaller and smaller FFTs, much like a Merge-sort first limits the sorting to the base cases.

The manner in which the C-T Algorithm does this *most commonly* is by dividing the problem in **half** (`N = N0 / 2`). That's not to say that the mixed-radix cases are not possible, but for the following reason, the "power-of-two" case is the most efficient, and thus the most used.

The main bottleneck for most FFT implementations now is not the implementation of the algorithm, but rather the hardware - processor pipelines and whatnot. These, obviously, are all built on binary logic fundamentals, leading to bandwidths that are almost exclusively 2<sup>N</sup>.

For this reason, an FFT that uses 2<sup>N</sup> bytes in memory will be computed more rapidly due to the fitting exactly in registers and exact subdivision of the original problems.

TL;DR: Pad your FFT vector with irrelevant data (0s) until it reaches the nearest power of 2. Then only use the valid resultant data.

Your exception, however, looks like you just ran out of memory. Are you using a 32-bit OS? If so you likely are running over your allotted 2GB process memory or some other constraint as a result of your large operation.

Comment: @LukasTheBoss well in that case you're more likely to run into errors. I'm no Android expert, but I'm certain the usual 2GB addressing limit is drastically reduced and memory management is much more tight. However, I don't think the 1.3MB that Java is allocating should be a problem here. So I guess my new question is what exactly is your question? It clearly says to choose 2 or 4 threads to run, and we've explained why your FFT should be a power of two. What error(s)/problems are you running into?

Comment: its funny when i have input vector of size 1 843 200 itt works very fast , but when i try this and i need this: 1 843 200+2 it throws same error : 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at edu.emory.mathcs.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFT_1D.bluestein_real_forward(Unknown Source)
 at edu.emory.mathcs.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFT_1D.realForward(Unknown Source)

Comment: when i try  1843 200+1 error when i try 1 843 120 error...the same

Comment: @LukasTheBoss That's very strange. I am suspecting some type of memory allocation error stemming from the algorithm attempting to automatically pad your array to a convenient number. If you are developing this for android, does this work outside of the android test environment? that is, with relaxed memory guidelines?

Comment: I need only real elemnts and fist 0.05 highest percent of all.

Comment: there will be some error with my java, becouse i tr y 460 600 compute time is 1 sec. but 460 602 it takes 1 minte and 1 sec:!

Comment: @LukasTheBoss While I do not at all eliminate errors in your Java code, from what I posted above, you should see that certain values necessarily *will* be faster than others due to how convenient they are four your FFT implementation to deal with. If you'd like, I'd suggest you post a new question with some of your actual code allowing SO to guide you through any errors you may be making.

Comment: @LukasTheBoss but yeah, 1 sec vs 1:01 is quite a difference haha most probably due to a programming error

Comment: :) in android it can be 3 miutes ...i have the oposite results than, must to be, with thgreads its slower tham with out threads...